# EqualityComparer<Uri>.Default.Equals() returning wrong result or what?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, equals, iequalitycomparer

Is there an explanation for this other than being a bug in the .NET Framework?  The `EqualityComparer<Uri>.Default.Equals()` method is saying that the following URLs are equal!

http://books.google.com/books?id=B84KAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=fletcher+sandford+tilton&source=bl&ots=ou8eF5REOG&sig=74fzA11Z8AENBtyCUcXEsXV06jQ&hl=en&ei=2rHTS9LaN4249gTOh_GrDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CA0Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=fletcher s

and

http://books.google.com/books?id=B84KAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=fletcher+sandford+tilton&source=bl&ots=ou8eF5REOG&sig=74fzA11Z8AENBtyCUcXEsXV06jQ&hl=en&ei=2rHTS9LaN4249gTOh_GrDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CA0Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=fletcher

Notice the space followed by 's' at the end of the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the concern (whether right or wrong) isn't in `EqualityComparer<Uri>.Default`. It calls into `Uri.Equals()` as it should.

Now, `Uri.Equals()` ignores differences on fragment alone. In a great many cases that is appropriate. In a great many it's not. Personally I wouldn't have had it as the default, but then since I'm not someone who coded it perhaps I don't know of some compelling reasons to have things as they are.

Note that this is documented.

Other decisions are also debatable (that it ignores case-difference on host components matches many practical concerns about URIs, but not how URI equality is defined in some specifications).

If you need a stricter equality than that, I suggest you define your own comparator:

```
public class UriStictEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Uri>
{
  public bool Equals(Uri x, Uri y)
  {
    return ReferenceEquals(x, y)
      ||
      (
        x != null
        &&
        y != null
        &&
        x.IsAbsoluteUri == y.IsAbsoluteUri
        &&
        x.ToString() == y.ToString()
      );
  }
  public int GetHashCode(Uri obj)
  {
    return obj == null ? 0 : obj.ToString().GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

Still, you may find that you want some cases the above considers unequal, to be equal too. E.g. you need to consider whether punycode and non-punycode versions are the same, whether escaped non-special characters should be unescaped, and so on. Uri's `Compare` method can be a benefit in such cases.

Comment: I like the idea of a custom comparer.  But how is comparing strings as you suggest better than Uri.Compare(url, value, UriComponents.AbsoluteUri, UriFormat.Unescaped, StringComparison.CurrentCulture).  Also, why is the IsAbsoluteUri check necessary?

Comment: Direct char-by-char comparison is an equality concept used in some Specs (RDF for example) and using ToString rather than AbsoluteUri prevents exceptions for partial URIs. When comparing an absolute and a partial, the difference in IsAbsoluteUri will give a faster answer than string comparison (not much though).
The Uri.Compare you suggest could do a nicer job in other cases, though it would have to never see a relative. Note also that most comparisons of URIs are not cultural-aware so Ordinal comparison may be closer to what you actually need.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are seeing is by-design. `Uri` fragments are ignored in its [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f83xtf15%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) implementation because they are not technically part of the URI itself. The [`Fragment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.fragment%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) part of your `Uri` is "#v=onepage&q=fletcher" (the # symbol and everything following it).

You can use a `Uri`'s [`Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.compare%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) method and specify which [`UriComponents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7767559y%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to include in the comparison.

Comment: Fragments are part of a URI, according to RFC 3986. They are not considered by some things that compare URIs with each other though.

Comment: Okay, so how about: Uri.Compare(url, value, UriComponents.AbsoluteUri, UriFormat.Unescaped, StringComparison.CurrentCulture)